# Android layout, setting buttons to have the same size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm am completely new to programming android apps in eclipse.

With that said, I based myself off code on the internet and and came up with this xml file for my layout. **I can not get the four buttons to have the same size**, and when I play around with the other parts, the progress bar and texts under it, they go bananas, displaying it off screen.

Could someone review the code and tell me what is gong on? I simply don't understand.
Here is a picture.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_currentDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Current Date"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/DailyCalorieProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:progress="80" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Calorie Limit : "
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2000  " >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Calories Left : "
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="552" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="____________________" >
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/buttonRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addFood"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Add Food"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addExercise"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Add Exercise"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/buttonRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_recWeight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Record Weight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sgstMeal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Suggest Meal/Exercise" />

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Edits:

It now almost works.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_currentDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CurrentDate"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/DailyCalorieProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:progress="80" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CalorieLimit"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CalorieLimitData" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CaloriesLeft"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CaloriesLeftData" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Line" >
    </TextView>



        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/buttonRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addFood"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/AddFood"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addExercise"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/AddExercise"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/buttonRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_recWeight"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/RecordWeight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sgstMeal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/SuggestedMeal_Exercise" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your layout isn't really "efficient". But anyway..to solve your problem you have to set your TableRow (the ones that contain your buttons) to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and all of your buttons to

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

0dip does not make anything. But because of the weight param android does the work for measuring the actual size anyway so you do not need to provide a "relevant" value

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. There is only one small problem, which is that the text in the last button is too big, so it gets displayed in two lines, and I don't think it fits in my table row.... Do you know how I can enlarge my table row, change the hight?

Comment: I put a picture, also removed the tableLayout inside the tableLayout, kinda redundant....

Comment: To fix the problem, I changed the name to something smaller. If you know what the problem is, I would love to know, but don't bother if its to much trouble, thanks again.

Comment: Try setting the height of the "two-line-button" to fill_parent

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't change your orginal post. If you want to add changes or updates (of your code) you should edit your post and add those updates below your orginal post and declare it. Because now my answer does not match your question anymore and you have a completely new question. This is confusing :)

Comment: It almost worked :) The bottom line is cut a little bit, but all the buttons are aligned. I got to read more about all these wrap_content, match_parent and fill_parent things.... Anyway, I'm going for the smaller name anyway's, its just better. Thanks!!